# Question about probability without knowing how many cases there is

Tags: probability

So the question is the following: John has a 0.25 probability of reaching work late, and I have to find out what's the probability of John only being late to work after day 4 (considering today is day 1).

So I tried going with the Binomial distribution route (X--Binomial(n,0.25) , with n being the number of events and 0,25 the probability of success), going with the opposite events rule (P(X>=5) = 1 - P(X<=4).
But since I don't have the number of events (n) , I'm having trouble solving the problem.

Is there anything I'm missing, or am I simply going by the wrong route? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $0.25$ is the probability of being late on **each day** (you didn't say that) and the events of being late on different days are **independent** (you didn't say that), then the event of being late **only** after the first four days is the event that he is not late on any of the first four days. $\text{That is } 0.75^4$.

Comment: Yeah 0.25 is the probability of being late on each day, i missworded. Thanks for the answer, I was using binomial distribution when I should be using geometric distribution.

Comment: @user3336801 : You can treat it as the probability that a binomially distributed random variable is equal to $0$ when the number of trials is $4$ and the probability of success on each trial is $0.25$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

The count of trials until a success has a **Geometric Distribution**.

$$X\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p)$$

But even without that, you want $\mathsf P($at least four days not late$)$.   What is the probability that four days in a row are not late?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. I see where my mistake was now, thanks.